# CentOS: Missing dependencies when installing vsftpd with MySQL

Tags: mysql, centos, pam

I'm using the guide at http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VirtualVsFtpd to install virtual users into vsftpd on CentOS. After getting partway through the installation, I get to the problem of missing dependencies.

`rpm -Uvh pam_mysql-0.7-0.5.rc1.el5.kb.2.i386.rpm` in terminal returns:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6 is needed by pam_mysql-1:0.7-0.5.rc1.el5.kb.2.i386
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by pam_mysql-1:0.7-0.5.rc1.el5.kb.2.i386
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by pam_mysql-1:0.7-0.5.rc1.el5.kb.2.i386
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by pam_mysql-1:0.7-0.5.rc1.el5.kb.2.i386
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by pam_mysql-1:0.7-0.5.rc1.el5.kb.2.i386
        libcrypt.so.1 is needed by pam_mysql-1:0.7-0.5.rc1.el5.kb.2.i386
        libcrypt.so.1(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by pam_mysql-1:0.7-0.5.rc1.el5.kb.2.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by pam_mysql-1:0.7-0.5.rc1.el5.kb.2.i386
        libdl.so.2 is needed by pam_mysql-1:0.7-0.5.rc1.el5.kb.2.i386
        libm.so.6 is needed by pam_mysql-1:0.7-0.5.rc1.el5.kb.2.i386
        libmysqlclient.so.15 is needed by pam_mysql-1:0.7-0.5.rc1.el5.kb.2.i386
        libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15) is needed by pam_mysql-1:0.7-0.5.rc1.el5.kb.2.i386
        libnsl.so.1 is needed by pam_mysql-1:0.7-0.5.rc1.el5.kb.2.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by pam_mysql-1:0.7-0.5.rc1.el5.kb.2.i386
        libz.so.1 is needed by pam_mysql-1:0.7-0.5.rc1.el5.kb.2.i386
```

Where can I find these missing dependencies?

Comment: This question is clearly [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Comment: Are you entirely sure that you are running CentOS 5 and not CentOS 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "proper" way to do this was alluded to, but not actually described in that wiki entry.

1. Install the [EPEL repository](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).
2. `yum install pam_mysql`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? (I asumming that you use CentOS 5.x)

```
yum localinstall pam_mysql-0.7-0.5.rc1.el5.kb.2.i386.rpm
```

Another way of doing is as root user:

```
rpm --import http://ftp.uni-bayreuth.de/linux/fedora-epel//RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-5

rpm -ivh http://epel.mirror.mendoza-conicet.gob.ar/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm

yum install pam_mysql
```

HTH